# If $f(x) = \int_0^{\sin x}\sqrt{1+t^2}dt$ and $g(y) = \int_3^y f(x)dx$ how do I find $g''(y)$?

Tags: calculus

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, I know that if $f(t)$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$, then $\frac d{dx} \int_c^x f(t)dt = f(x)$. However, here $f(x)$ is another definite integral. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: In the same way as you approached the first one. You will need to apply the same FTC plus the Chain Rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By FTC

$$g'(y)=f(y)=\int_0^{\sin(y)} \sqrt{1+t^2}dt$$

$$=F(\sin(y))$$ with $$F(u)=\int_0^u \sqrt{1+t^2}dt$$

thus

$$g''(y)=\sqrt{1+\sin^2(y)}\cos(y)$$